# Iterate multiple Arrays in 1 foreach in typescript and not in html in Angular 4

Tags: angular

Is there any way to iterate 2 arrays in 1 foreach loop.
For eg.

```
for(let obj of [key.entryTime], let obj1 of [key.exitTime]) {
    for(let key in obj, let key 1 in obj1) {
        this.entryTimeList.push({position: i, 
        entryTime: obj[key], exitTime: obj1[key1]});
        i++;
    }
}
```

I have seen this in C#, Php etc but for angular I didn't find any solution which is why posting it here. I even found a way out for iterating 2 arrays using ngFor in html. Is this possible or I will have to write another forEach.

Comment: foreach operates on only one array at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate two arrays with the same index like this

```
arr1.forEach((item,index) => console.log("item from Arr1 - " + item, "Item from Arr2 - " + arr2[index]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't get you didn't have indexes.

In this case, you can take a look at [**this page**](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Loop_over_multiple_arrays_simultaneously#JavaScript), that will give you several ways of doing it.